# why the wrapped function in this decorator runs automatically without neither of them being called?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, python-decorators, syntactic-sugar

I am exploring how to use decorator in python 3. I typed these codes in the editor and clicked the 'run' button.

```
log_stat = False


def decorator():
    def wrapper(func):
        global log_stat
        while not log_stat:
            username = input("username")
            password = input("password")
            if username == "123" and password == "456":
                func()
                log_stat = True
            else:
                print("try again")
    return wrapper


@decorator()
def welcome():                 
    print("welcome")
```

I was expecting nothing to be displayed on the screen since I thought what I did was just defining functions but not calling or executing them. But python asked me to input username and password, which seems like it had actually run the wrapped function.

What's the real reason for this? And how can I just define the function without triggering the wrapped one?

Comment: Which editor are we talking about here?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning. I am using PyCharm's editor.

Answer (score 3):

A decorator is a callable that takes a class or function and returns a class or function.  The decorator syntax is

```
@decorator  # note no ()
def function():
    ...
```

What you're doing is calling `decorator`, then using the result of that call (`wrapper`) to decorate `welcome`.  `wrapper` therefore runs immediately.

What you intended to write was probably

```
def decorator(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        global log_stat
        while not log_stat:
            username = input("username")
            password = input("password")
            if username == "123" and password == "456":
                log_stat = True
                return func(*args, **kwargs)           
            else:
                print("try again")  # I would raise an exception here
    return wrapper


@decorator
def welcome():                 
    print("welcome")
```

Note that `wrapper` takes arguments in this version.  This is because when you decorate `welcome`, it gets replaced with `wrapper`.  So if your `welcome` function took arguments, your `wrapper` would also have to take them in order to pass them to the original function.

Comment: Sorry about my previous failed comment, i didn't know how to properly insert code in comment. Thank you very much!!! I've rewritten my code, I added some arguments to `welcome` and had them printed and it worked! So in this case, the `wrapper` doesn't actually USE the arguments, it just STORE those arguments for `func` to use? Is this correct?

Comment: @yjyj It *can* use the arguments, it just doesn't in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've called the decorator when using it. That means it runs at import time. You should remove the parentheses.

```
@decorator
def welcome():                 
    print("welcome")
```

(It is possible to define a decorator that is called at import time, si that it accepts parameters; but to do so you have to implement another level of wrapping, so that the function returns a decorator which in turn returns a function which wraps the original.)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I added another outer decorator, gave it parameters so that I could call it when import and tested it. It worked! So after import time, the outermost decorator is replaced with the inner decorator which the outermost one returned, and when I call the wrapped function, what really happens is the inner decorator(with the name of the outer one) being called? Is this correct?